# How do I repeatedly search & replace a long string of text in vim?

Tags: vim, replace

I'm aware of the vim replace command, which is of the form, eg:

```
:%s/old/new/gc
```

But what if either of these strings is long? How can I use something like visual selection mode, the clipboard or vim registers instead of having to type the old/new text in?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The `%s` command will replace over the entire buffer, so you won't need to do it more than once.

Comment: I used the word repeatedly to emphasize that I can't just amend the text in place because it exists multiple times in my script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to the manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to insert the contents of a register into the current position in the command line.  The manual also claims that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> inserts the text highlighted with the mouse into the command line.  Remember that in X11 and some other systems, you can also paste text into a program from the system clipboard using the middle mouse button or a menu command in your terminal emulator.

Comment: So, for example, yank something into the default register, then type `:%s/` then ctrl-r `"` to put that in, then your second `/`, then a replacement pattern - which you could also have yanked, perhaps into a different register.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `q:` to bring up a command-line window.  This lets you use all the vim editing commands to edit the vim command line, including `p` to paste.  So, you could copy the text into a register, paste it into the command line window, and execute it that way.

I recently discovered this feature via [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/).

Comment: Dang, I've been missing this for sooo long =)

Answer (score 2):

I think to avoid have your command line be huge you can use this to solve your issue

```
:%s/foo/\=@a/g
```

That replaces "foo" with whatever is in register a.

Comment: Note: [`\=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-special) is special in this way only for the replacement part (it has a [different meaning in the pattern part](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5c=)). Also, the text following `\=` in the replacement can be any [Vim expression](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expression-syntax). The [`@r` expression](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-register) evaluates to the contents of register `r`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do a substitute with a long complicated search pattern, here's a good way of going about it:

Try out the search pattern using some test cases and refine it until you have the pattern you want. I find `incsearch` really helps, especially with complicated regular expressions.

You can then use :%s//new to replace all instances of the last searched for pattern.

If you've entered a pattern and want to copy it out of the search history, you can use `q/` to bring up a command line window containing recent search patterns very similar to the `q:` one that contains recent command history.

On the other hand, if you're asking about how to copy and paste text into the substitute command:

I'd write the pattern out in insert mode and yank the search and replacement into two distinct registers using, say, `"ay` and `"by` and then use `:%s/<C-R>a/<C-R>b/gc` to do the substitute. There are lots of variations of the yank command, but this one should also work automatically when using a visual selection.

If you're copying in text from the clipboard, you can use `<C-R>*` to paste it's contents in insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following mapping in my .vimrc

```
vnoremap <leader>r "ry:%s/^Rr/
```

So I visually select the thing I want to replace, and hit `,r`, type the replacement and hit return. If I want to paste the replacement, I yank it before selecting the text to replace, and then use `<C-r>"` to paste it as the replacement before hitting return.

Note: to insert `^R` in your .vimrc, you actually type `<C-v><C-r>`.